# DownloadOperation.StartAsync() has slow start up time

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I'm using the BackgroundDownloader class in my windows-store-app to download files, and I'm really wondering if I'm doing something wrong since the start up time for the download is so long for big files.

**Code:**

```
Util.DebugWriteln("Creating downloader");
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
dwo = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(request), destination);
Util.DebugWriteln("DownloadOperation created");
```

This is the call that starts the download and takes such a long time:

```
Util.DebugWriteln("Starting download async");
await dwo.StartAsync().AsTask(progressCallback);
```

**Log:**

> 7/23/2013 1:13:20 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DownloadFile(): Attempting download of file: /200MB.zip
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:20 PM:  Util.cs->GetStorageFile(): Getting storage file for: 200MB.zip
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:20 PM:  Synergica.cs->DownloadFile(): Creating downloader
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:20 PM:  Synergica.cs->DownloadFile(): DownloadOperation created
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:20 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DownloadFile(): Starting download async

29 seconds later

> 7/23/2013 1:13:49 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DefaultProgressCallback(): Download progress for file: 200MB.zip -> 0%
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:50 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DefaultProgressCallback(): Download progress for file: 200MB.zip -> 28%
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:50 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DefaultProgressCallback(): Download progress for file: 200MB.zip -> 56%
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:51 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DefaultProgressCallback(): Download progress for file: 200MB.zip -> 84%
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:51 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DefaultProgressCallback(): Download progress for file: 200MB.zip -> 100%
>
> 7/23/2013 1:13:51 PM:  ThreadHandler.cs->DownloadFile(): Success

Am I calling the StartAsync() method in a wrong way? (Sitting on the same LAN as the server hosting the file)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something caused by other things, like slow DNS lookup? What happens if you download a small file and then a large file in the same process/run?

Comment: Small files finish instantly, even when downloading just one or many small and big ones simultaneously.

Comment: Can't think of anything causing this right now then, probably except a slow drive or some kind of mechanic working in background first (either client side to manage the background download or server side generating the large file first). Which would lead to another question: Does the download start instantly in a standard browser?

Comment: Just tried it, browser downloads instantly in barely 3 seconds :/

Comment: Can you try it on another system?

Comment: Just tried it on a Microsoft Surface RT and my coworkers computer, both had the same issue (but both are also on the same network).

Comment: Hm no idea really, but I'd try to determine a pattern, e.g. download files with different sized and try to get some kind of graph. E.g. to see whether the delay really depends on the file size or whether there's some sudden change.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to keep looking, thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible that first it has to request the amount of space for the file on the disk before downloading it? I haven't used large files in the Windows Store yet.

Comment: Can you try downloading from an IP instead of a Url to make sure it is not about DNS?

Comment: Please try `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;` too.

Comment: @NateDiamond: Might be the case, no idea how to optimize it then though.

Comment: @mostruash: I'll try it as soon as I get back in the office monday.

Comment: Been working with this for a bit now, does not appear to be a DNS nor a proxy issue.